# Can't connect to HyperSQL / HSQLDB database as new user

Tags: java, database, hsqldb, hypersql

I have started HyperSQL like this:

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:/data/db --dbname.0 some_db
```

Then if I try to connect to it like:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/some_db", "SA", "");
```

Everything works fine. Now when I add new user like:

```
CREATE USER new_user PASSWORD "some_password" ADMIN;
```

I can not connect to HyperSQL server using new user data (also after restarting):

```
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/some_db", "new_user", "some_password");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user name is case-sensitive only if it is double-quoted when created

```
CREATE USER "new_user" PASSWORD "some_password" ADMIN;
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/some_db", "new_user", "some_password");
```

In your example, the actual user name is NEW_USER and you can connect as this user if you use uppercase in connection sting.